# React onMouseEnter/onMouseOver event cancels scrolling to section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

i have a navbar consisting of icons which link to different sections of my page (duh). i use a state to track if an icon is currently hovered so a div can pop up explaining the icon. both of these features work just fine, however, if i hover over ANY item while the page is scrolling to a section, the scroll stops immidiately.

video of the behavior: https://puu.sh/JmCjE/496bddfb10.mp4 (clicked FAQ, scroll works, clicked Process, scroll works, clicked FAQ again and then hovered over (not clicked) another item, scroll cancels)

code (i removed anything styling related):

```
<ul>
  {navbarItems.map((Item, i) => (
    <Link key={i} href={Item.link}>
      <motion.li
      onMouseOver={() => setIsHovering(i)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovering(false)}
      >
        <Item.component />
        {isHovering === i && (
          <motion.div>
            <motion.div>
              <h4>{Item.name}</h4>
            </motion.div>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </motion.li>
    </Link>
  ))}
</ul>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: note this is using framer motion https://www.framer.com/docs/component/

Comment: i dont have an answer for you yet. but this may be related? https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/310 also check: https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1085

Comment: Can you post the onclick/Scroll logic? If there is any, it might be possible to work around this using state.

Comment: @MattPengelly this is what an item looks like: { component: MdOutlinePeople, link: "#about-us", name: "Über uns" }. MdOutlinePeople is the icon, the link is the id of the section i wanna scroll to, the name is what i want to be shown when i hover an icon inside the navbar. so the scroll to a section based on its id is cancelled. so not really any logic going on

Comment: i figured it was all handled by framer-motion, seems to be the case. did you check those issues i posted above? it seems as if the state changes while animating an issue occurs within framer-motion itself is my guess

Comment: @MattPengelly i checked it out, yes. however, i couldn't really make sense of it, since i'm a beginner. i changed all my motion divs in the conditional rendering to normal divs and the scroll is not cancelled anymore, so this has indeed something to do with framer motion. so thank you for that already!